# Way to specify a common column value to all VALUES in an INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, insert, default

I've got a table that's going to have thousands of rows in it.  I have a bunch of INSERT statements in a text file I read into the db for testing:

```
INSERT into my_table (c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES
   ("aaaAA",   "aaaAB",   "aaaAC", "foo"),
   ("aaaBA",   "aaaBB",   "aaaBC", "foo"),
   [ ... etc ... ]
   ;

 INSERT into my_table (c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES
   ("bbbAA",  "bbbAB",  "bbbAC",  "bar"),
   ("bbbBA",  "bbbBB",  "bbbBC",  "bar"),
   [ ... etc ... ]
   ;
```

This all works great, but it would be cleaner (and easier) if I could so something like:

```
 INSERT into my_table (c1, c2, c3, c4="foo") VALUES
   ("aaaAA",   "aaaAB",   "aaaAC"),
   ("aaaBA",   "aaaBB",   "aaaBC"),
   [ ... etc ... ]
   ;
```

My google-fu hasn't turned up anything.  Is this possible?